# Unsupported sObjects for List Controllers

Tags: apex, controller, limits, standardsetcontroller

I am new to SFDC and have only been developing for about 6 months, in this time I have noticed some limitations around List Controllers and some standard objects.

Is there any way (programatically) that I could find which Objects cannot be instantiated with a List Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot detect these failures in a safe manner purely in Apex Code. Attempting to give a StandardSetController an unsupported type causes an immediate halt of the program. Even using a try-catch block will result in the same immediate failure, even if the list is determined dynamically using a query string (e.g. Database.query). I suppose you could get a global describe of all SObjects in your organization, then query them 100 at a time using Visualforce remoting, catching those exceptions client-side and generating a list. However, I daresay that such a program would probably take a while to run.

As Itai's answer points out, however, you do know the list of standard supported types; if it's not in the documentation, you should presume it is not supported, even if your code seems to work with that type. Custom objects that use "__c" as the suffix should all be safe, as well as the standard objects listed. Other types of related metadata, like "__Share" are also not supported.

All that said, you can choose to use your own custom pagination. It's not as handy as using a StandardSetController, because each time you query the database, you might get a different subset as records are added/removed from the database.

If you absolutely need up to 10,000 records in a list using pagination for an unsupported type, consider querying all of the records to the page using the [QueryResultIterator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_queryresultiterator.htm), and then rolling your own JavaScript-based pagination, or using some [jQuery pagination](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/) module, or some other code you could find by using a query.

Answer (score 1):

According to this page ([Standard List Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_about.htm)), the following standard objects are supported :

Account

Asset

Campaign

Case

Contact

Contract

Idea

Lead

Opportunity

Order

Product2

Solution

User

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer how to use objects that are not supported, though.

Comment: I agree with @sfdcfox , thanks for taking the time to try and help though.